# C# How to relate a selected item in a ListView with the real object?

Tags: c#, winforms, list, listview

I'm struggling to go from a selected item in a List View to the real object it is representing. To keep the question simple, I have a few things:

Two lists of objects of the homemade class `personaje`:

```
public List<personaje> nuevosDeudores = new List<personaje>(); 

public List<personaje> deudores = new List<personaje>();
```

Now I have a ListView that shows `nuevosDeudores` and I want to select one item and click button3 to delete it from that list and add it to the list `deudores`.

```
    private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (listView1.SelectedIndices.Count == 1)
        {
            ListViewItem item = listView1.SelectedItems[0];
            jugador.deudores.Add(***i need to put the "personaje" object reference here***);
            jugador.nuevosDeudores.RemoveAll(x => x.identificador == Convert.ToInt32(listView1.SelectedItems[0].SubItems[0].Text));
            listView1.Items.Remove(item);
        }
    }
```

As you can see, I have found a way to delete the `personaje` object from one list, but I don't know how to add it to the other list. I only have the lousy ListViewItem reference, I don't know how to directly "talk about it" so of speak :)

EDIT:
I add the code where I populate the two lists

```
        deudores.Add(new personaje("Dimitri", 1));
        deudores[0].seLeDebe = 5000;
        deudores[0].paciencia = 4;
        deudores.Add(new personaje("Marcelo", 1));  
        deudores[1].seLeDebe = 2500;  
        deudores[1].paciencia = 10;

        nuevosDeudores.Add(new personaje("Pascuale", 1));
        nuevosDeudores[0].oferta = 3000;
        nuevosDeudores[0].paciencia = 10;
        nuevosDeudores.Add(new personaje("Señor Anselmo", 1));
        nuevosDeudores[1].oferta = 6000;
        nuevosDeudores[1].paciencia = 7;
        nuevosDeudores.Add(new personaje("Snatch", 1));
        nuevosDeudores[2].oferta = 2000;
        nuevosDeudores[2].paciencia = 5;
```

And here is the code I use to populate the ListView

```
    private void PopularListview()
    {
        listView1.Items.Clear();
        int cuenta = 0;
        ListViewItem[] item = new ListViewItem[20];
        foreach (personaje deudor in jugador.deudores)
        {
            string paciencia = "";
            for (int i = 0; i < deudor.paciencia / 2; i++) paciencia += "|";
            string[] row = { deudor.identificador.ToString(), deudor.nombre, deudor.seLeDebe.ToString(), paciencia };
            item[cuenta] = new ListViewItem(row);
            listView1.Items.Add(item[cuenta]);
            cuenta++;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Three solutions for a single problem, I'll try them all. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You did not state anything, I'll assume Windows Forms.

Each ListViewItem has a [Tag](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listviewitem.tag%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) that can be used for exactly this scenario.

When creating your ListViewItems, *put your object into that tag*. When the user selects a ListViewItem, look into it's tag to get the object you put there:

```
jugador.deudores.Add(item.Tag as personaje);
```

**Edit:**

When inserting into the ListView, add a line that sets the Tag of each item:

```
        item[cuenta] = new ListViewItem(row);
        item[cuenta].Tag = deudor;
        listView1.Items.Add(item[cuenta]);
```

Comment: Yes, sorry, it's Windows Forms in VS 2010. Could you type a code example with the code I provided?

Comment: You never provided the part where you put your items into the list, so that part is impossible to do until you post more code.

Comment: I thought it was irrelevant and wanted to keep the question simple. I edited my question with the code now

Comment: @CarlesAlcolea Have a look please. Sidenote: if you keep your code free of national language, people on the internet or developers in general will have a much easier time helping you. Try english class and variable names.

Comment: Now I write questions in stackoverflow 0.001% of the time versus the times i search/read it, but I'll keep english in mind :)

Answer (score 0):

I guess are having problem while adding from one list to another, which is of same type. If so try the below code by replacing your second line inside `if`.

```
jugador.deudores.AddRange(nuevosDeudores.Where(x => x.identificador == Convert.ToInt32(listView1.SelectedItems[0].SubItems[0].Text)));
```

Answer (score 0):

Get selected person id. Then you will be able to get person from list and manipulate lists any way you want:

```
private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (listView1.SelectedIndices.Count == 1)
    {
        ListViewItem item = listView1.SelectedItems[0];            
        int id = Convert.ToInt32(item.SubItems[0].Text);
        var personaje = jugador.nuevosDeudores.First(x => x.identificador == id);

        listView1.Items.Remove(item); // remove from ListView
        jugador.nuevosDeudores.Remove(personaje); // remove from List

        jugador.deudores.Add(personaje); // add to another List
        // Create and add ListViewItem to listView2
    }
}
```